# ¿Por qué no puedo recontar los votos de una votación en Decide a pesar de que los votos se almacenan?

Tags: python, django

Estoy usando Decide, el software de votación electrónica que usamos en la ETSII en EGC (https://github.com/EGCETSII/decide). Luego de cumplir con el proceso de instalación, me encuentro un fallo a la hora de hacer el recuento de los votos:

1. Instalo y configuro la aplicación siguiente las instrucciones
2. hago ./manage.py runserver
3. Entro en el admin de Django
4. Creo una votación, sus preguntas, sus autoridades, su censo, y dos usuarios
5. Inicio (Start) la votación
6. Abro una pestaña de la cabina de votación (booth) y uso los usuarios que he creado para hacer dos votos. Los votos se almacenan aparentemente bien.
7. Paro la votación y no me da error
8. Hago el recuento (Tally) y me da un fallo lo que ya no me permite hacer la visualización (Visualizer) de los resultados.

El mensaje de error que me sale es el siguiente
[image: Error que sale en el navegador]

He intentado crear de nuevo todos los usuarios y no me funciona. También he intentado a cambiar las IPs en el localsettings.py y no he tenido éxito. He probado localhost:8000, direcciones locales 10.*.*.* y otras y tampoco. Pego mi localsettings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

# Modules in use, commented modules that you won't use
MODULES = [
    'authentication',
    'base',
    'booth',
    'census',
    'mixnet',
    'postproc',
    'store',
    'visualizer',
    'voting',
]

APIS = {
    'authentication': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'base': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'booth': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'census': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'mixnet': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'postproc': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'store': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'visualizer': 'http://localhost:8000',
    'voting': 'http://localhost:8000',
}

BASEURL = 'http://localhost:8000'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'practica',
        'PASSWORD': 'practica',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# number of bits for the key, all auths should use the same number of bits
KEYBITS = 256
```

Answer (score 0):

Tras seguir los pasos descrito he podido reproducir el error cuando al realizar la votación con la cuenta de administrador haces logout, luego cierras la votación y haces tally.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto elimina tu token pero solo cierras la sesión en el módulo booth por lo que pierdes los permisos para realizar el tally.
Para solucionarlo tienes que cerrar la sesión en el módulo admin y volver a inciar sesión con tu cuenta administrador para obtener un nuevo token.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]